# Horizontal Recycler view auto scrolling error

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, smooth-scrolling

I have this `RecyclerView` that functions as a ticker, the auto scrolling works fine at first but after a period of time it becomes strange (back and forth) and the `RecyclerView` gets stuck at an item without smooth scrolling anymore, can anyone help me.

this is my layout manager:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(HomeActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false) {
        @Override
        public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position) {
            LinearSmoothScroller smoothScroller = new  LinearSmoothScroller(HomeActivity.this) {
                private static final float SPEED = 5500f;// Change this value (default=25f)
                @Override
                protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
                    return SPEED / displayMetrics.densityDpi;
                }
            };
            smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
            startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
        }

    };
    rvTicker.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

this is my auto scrolling function:

```
public void autoScroll(){
    speedScroll = 0;
    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        int count = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(count == tickerAdapter.getItemCount())
                count = 0;
            if(count < tickerAdapter.getItemCount()){
                rvTicker.smoothScrollToPosition(++count);
                handler.postDelayed(this,speedScroll);
            }
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable,speedScroll);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED, I tweaked the `autoscroll` function:

```
public void autoScroll(){
    speedScroll = 0;
    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        int count = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(count == tickerAdapter.getItemCount())
                count = 0;
            else {
                if(count < tickerAdapter.getItemCount()){
                    rvTicker.smoothScrollToPosition(++count);
                    handler.postDelayed(this,speedScroll);
                }else {
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
            Log.wtf("tickerAdapter.getItemCount()", tickerAdapter.getItemCount()+"");
            Log.wtf("count", count+"");
            Log.wtf("++count", ++count+"");
            Log.wtf("==============","=============");
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable,speedScroll);
}
```

Comment: Hi, perfect work out for autoscroll. thanks. But when the click or scroll manually stops auto scrolling. Is there any way to maintain it on user click/scroll?